# show clock with php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show server time on my web page. I'd done client time with javascript codes but how I can show server time?

is any zendFramework classes do this?

I'm using below javascript code to show client time:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
        var today=new Date();

        var h=today.getHours();
        var m=today.getMinutes();
        var s=today.getSeconds();

        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m=checkTime(m);
        s=checkTime(s);

        document.getElementById("time_section").innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
        t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);

}

function checkTime(i)
{
        if (i<10)
         {
              i="0" + i;
         }
        return i;
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you posting irrelevant code? :)

Comment: waht about Ajax callback

Comment: you could have answered your own question with a quick google search.

Comment: You really should go and read a few things about the difference between client-side and server-side. It seems that you don't quite understand the concept yet.

Comment: @baudday, fvu, Bono: The question might be badly asked, but come on, make an effort to see what is really being asked. Yes, it does not have much to do with PHP, but aside from gowri, noone's been even close to solving his problem: dynamically displaying server time.

Comment: oh man my bad! i didn't realize it was asking for real time. I thought it was just current time.

Comment: @fvu: read my answer - it's not as simple as that - you need to keep it refreshed. If you think it's as easy as calling AJAX once a second (the trivial answer), you're the one in need of a downvote.

Comment: @Amadan why are you telling me "make an effort", all I asked is why he was posting irrelevant code. It wasn't meant to put him down or anything. I genuinly wanted to see relevant code?

Comment: @Bono: Because the code *was* relevant.

Comment: @Bono: It illustrates exactly what he meant. Many people, obviously skipping the "irrelevant" code, jumped to conclusion that he wanted to display the server time at the time of page load. The asker's code was much more eloquent than his English, making it obvious that he wants a real-time clock, one that actually flips digits every second or so. If you take a look at h3nr1k's solution, or mine, you can see that we made minimal modifications of his `startTime` code to solve his problem. Now let me ask you: if we kept his code and changed just one line in it, how was it irrelevant?

Comment: @Amadan because OP does not specify he want's a real time clock nor does he specify it's to be done in JS. All he says is that the code below is used to show client side. If he said any of those thing I would have granted you that and would have had some humble pie, but non of that is to be found anywhere. Just because his _client_ code shows that, does not by any means mean that his server code is supposed to be the same. And on a completely different note; you need to chill out and stop being "rude" (with a lack of a better word).

Comment: @Amadan and before you call me rude with my first comment, how could anyone consider it rude. It even has a smiley in there for crying out loud. And one way or the other, if you or OP finds it rude I apologize, because it was honestly not meant that way. You on the other hand don't seem to have any indication of being "polite".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11993/discussion-between-amadan-and-bono)

Answer (score 7):

to show the server time use the date function:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

if you mean a realtime clock you can't do that with php, stick with javascript for that

Comment: Perfectly correct, and perfectly useless to the asker, as he obviously means realtime clock.

Comment: You could as well print the time var from your php and then constantly increment it with JS (obviously there could be a few (mili)seconds delay depending on the page load time), but it's possible. (note that OP tagged his question with JS).

Comment: @Amadan no, he didn't obviously mean a realtime clock. he wanted the server time. and that's why i said "if you mean a realtime clock..."

Comment: @Vlad: I'm being not particularly polite because many people were not being particularly polite or fair to the asker. It's frustrating to see a comment like "Why are you posting irrelevant code?" being upvoted 6 times when the code he posted is the key to understanding the problem. If you read the code, it *is* obvious what he meant (i.e. same as *this*, but with different numbers). He put tags PHP and JS because he may not know what technology would get him what he wants. You did say "If you mean a realtime clock...", but what followed was not even close to sufficient to solve his problem.

Comment: @Amadan as i said. everyone is seeing this in it's own way. it's the asker responsability to state his problem as clear as possible. "How can i create a realtime clock with javascript based on the server time?" - would have clarified everything. i'm just saying. i have stated my views and i'm out.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code so, the setTimeout function only increments the clock in the client every minute, then initialize the `today` javascript variable with the server time using php, like this:

```
// time() returns seconds, multiply by 1000 to get millisenconds
var today = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000?>);
```

Then the javascript clock should keep going with the server time in the client

Optionally, you can synchronize with the server time by doing an ajax request every certain amount of time (p.e an hour)

Answer (score 1):

Ask the server for the time by AJAX, as UNIX timestamp (PHP function `time()`). When it arrives, get the difference from the local timestamp (`var timeDiff = new Date() - serverTime * 1000`); modify your not-quite-irrelevant code to show `new Date() + timeDiff` instead of `new Date()`.

Let's try some code:

```
var timeDiff;
$.ajax('time.php', {      
  success: function(serverTime) {
    timeDiff = new Date() - serverTime * 1000;
    startTime();
  }
});
```

replace `newDate()` with `newDate() + timeDiff` in your `startTime`. On the serverside, it's simple, in `time.php`:

```
header('Content-Type: text-json');
echo time();
```

Didn't check, so there might be bugs. Caveat emptor.

h3nr1x's solution would also work, but this way you won't have to worry about going out of sync.

A small glitch is that the time calculation on the clientside is all being done in the local time zone; this will affect you if you cross the DST time at the different time than the server, and in the meantime the time shown would be incorrect. I do not know the way to set the time zone of the JavaScript's `Date` object, or if it is even possible. :(

Answer (score 0):

**Set server timezone**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

**Will display 17:16:18**

```
$currentTime = date("H:i:s");
```

see [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for confiruation options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with AJAX. Have a php page which echo the current time and update it every second or whatever with the ajax.

Comment: One request every second? No thanks.

Comment: @Amadan please be more polite. everyone sees the problem differently